# This is a question about material replacement

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, properties, object-mode

If there is more than one material in object mode, is there any way to leave the material in the existing slot and change it to a material in another slot? I'm looking for something similar to the'assign' button in edit mode.

Comment: Hi and welcome. There is a data-block dropdown (texture ball icon) below the list of materials which allows you to swap out the material by another used in the scene. Does this help? BTW: Please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, thanks.

Comment: @brockmann Thank you for answer.
But not the answer I want.
To explain exactly what I want, it means a button that can directly change the material assigned to slot 1 to the material in slot 2.
I don't want to swap material in slot 1.

Comment: @brockmann Currently, I am thinking of merging the material in slot 1 and slot 2 and giving the fac value to the'mix shader' to fade, but this is also a problem because it is not input globally in the scene.

Comment: You can use a driver for the *fac* value with a custom property or the position of an empty. Then it's globally in the scene if this is what you want.

Comment: @Blunder Thanks for the reply
I never thought of a driver
Thanks to it, it was solved
It would be better if the first method worked, but this method is also not bad, thank you